# Opencart Popup Window not sizing correctly

Tags: popup, opencart

I am using OpenCart 1.5.6 and a version of the YooResponsive theme.

When I am in my shopping cart and choose to Estimate Shipping, I add my state/zip and click the button and I get a popup box that is too small.

Both the right side and the bottom are cut off. The HTML code on the live site is:

```html
<div id="colorbox" class="" style="padding-bottom: 57px; padding-right: 28px; top: 456px; left: 653px; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; width: 572px; height: 343px;">
```

If I use firebug to change `width: 572px; height: 343px;` to `width: 600px; height: 400px;` it looks correct but I can't seem to find anywhere in the code to make these changes.

This looks like it is hard coded rather than brought in from a css file.

In my `cart.tpl` I have the following javascript code:

```js
 $.colorbox({
               overlayClose: true,
               opacity: 0.5,
               width: '600px',
               height: '400px',
               href: false,
               html: html
            });
```

This code seems to be setup right but why is it not displaying at the correct size?

It also does this with the Terms and Conditions link that shows up at the end of the checkout process. I imagine that if I check other pop-up boxes it would do the same.

One thing I noticed was that for both pop-up boxes (which are different sizes) the measurements that change are exactly the same as the padding in the HTML code (`padding-bottom: 57px; padding-right: 28px;`). So the height is always `57px` smaller and the width is always `28px` smaller. If I use firefox to change the padding in the HTML code above it does nothing to make it display correctly, only by changing the height and width does anything change.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you tell me a link that i can chevk, your approach with .js is correct this is the way the colorbox object works, so i do not know why you are having these problems.

Comment: You would have to go to the page below and act like you are ordering something. Just click "add to cart" at the bottom and on the cart page ask it to Estimate Shipping. http://zing-cards.com/dev/storefront/index.php?route=product/product&path=59&product_id=50

Comment: Hmm, seems that colorbox is always opening the window at 600x400 while these are the dimensions of the whole container with all the paddings, borders, margins, etc. Try to adjust the width and height to `width: '628px'` and `height: '457px'` - since You cannot control padding and margins - these are calculated - You can provide at least pre-calculated dimensions. But be aware that on different resolutions colorbox can also calculate different paddings...

Comment: So I tried to change it in the $.colorbox script above at the end of the cart.tpl but it didn't work. Is there another place that I can change the code?

Comment: I just checked and it changes the size of the window in the code (I set it to 800 x 600) but the edges are still cut off. The only way I can get it to display right is to change the inline css style to be the correct size but I can't find where to make the calculations that create this code to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind, I got it! I had a stylesheet attached to the site that was changing the box-sizing

The code was:

```
* {   
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing:    border-box;
   box-sizing:         border-box;
}
```

And I just added this code to the stylesheet.css to override it:

```
#colorbox {   
   -webkit-box-sizing: content-box !important;
   -moz-box-sizing:    content-box !important;
   box-sizing:         content-box !important;
   }
```